# Getting StackOverflowError when using URLRewriteFilter

Tags: tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

i am trying to use `UrlRewriteFilter` but i am getting error

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruQMj.jpg)

maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
    <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>confPath</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

and my rule:

```
<rule>
    <from>/admin/main</from>
    <to>/views/admin/main-page.xhtml</to>
</rule>
```

this rule returs error when i am go to url `localhost:8080/admin/main`

Comment: what is the problem ? help please

Comment: How did you resolve this ?

Comment: how did you resolve it?